# How can I add countries to the "3G" list on my router?

Tags: router, 3g

My router (MR3420 v1 00000000) does not have my country listed in the "3G" countries list. I downloaded and installed the latest firmware from the TP-LINK website, but no dice. Is there any way to add countries to the list of countries?

[image: this page]

Comment: Does the router support 3G networks in your country?

Comment: It sounds like your `3G Modem` isn't supported by your `Mobile ISP` I would contact them for support.  Despite it calling itself a router it actually is a modem.